# запросы в бд на джанго

Tags: python, django

Ребята, я только начинаю работать с питоном и джанго. Задача, нужно посчитать кол-во не выполненных задач по всем пользавателям. Вот мой код:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tasks.models import TodoItem
from django.db.models import Count

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Count TopUsers"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("--top-rated", dest='top-users', type=int, default=25)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for u in User.objects.all():
            u.tasks.filter(is_completed=True).count():
```

но я немогу их суммировать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Task.objects.filter(is_completed=True).count()
```

Comment: видимо я не точно поставил вопрос. Здесь u.tasks.filter(is_completed=True).count() я получаю количество не выполненных задач по каждаму пользавателю, а мне нужна сумма всех невыполненных задач в бд

Comment: @Evgeny код из моего ответа возвращает количество **всех** выполненных задач, всех пользователей. Поменяйте `True` на `False` - будут невыполненные. Цикл не нужен.

Comment: всё правильно, но мне нужна сумма всех невыполненных задач. не по пользавателю, а вообще всех

Comment: @Evgeny повторяю, код в моём ответе именно это и делает.

Comment: спасибо. Всё работает, устал вчера уже видимо